# Disable internet from wifi only

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, lan, internet-connection

I am trying to disable internet from my wifi only, but i need it on lan.
Is there a way to disable internet from the wifi only but not from Lan and the wifi must still on ?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Generally you can login to your WiFi router and disable it.

Comment: All you need is the router/modem manual online and login to Wifi menu and disable

Comment: Windows 10?????

Comment: If you want to prevent yourself from using wifi, but others can use wifi then don't worry because ethernet will have been set up to have priority.

Comment: thank you guys for your response, i think the best answer is from @Velo Traveler

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "probably not" for most types of home Wifi routers. If you post the model of router that you have, we could get you a more accurate answer, but nearly every home router I've seen had no distinction between wired and wireless clients except for whether they were allowed to administer the device.

But I can think of a couple of workarounds:

Workaround 1: Use a 2nd WiFi router:

- Set up its WAN port manually, WITH NO DHCP.
- Assign the WAN port a static IP address in your network that is NOT in the DHCP range used by your regular WiFi router.
- Do NOT create a default route. If the router insists that you fill in a default route, make the destination an IP address on the LAN side or try 0.0.0.0.
- Use a new subnet on the LAN side of the router, let's say 192.168.10.0/24
- Do not set up any static routes on the 2nd router.
- Add a security rule to the 2nd router allows traffic from the new network, 192.168.10.0/24, to your old network on the first router.
- Add another security rule on the 2nd router that drops all other traffic (that should be the default but it's nice to have it explicitly listed).
- WiFi and LAN users on the 2nd router will be able to reach your LAN, but their traffic to the Internet will get dropped.
- Disable WiFi on your first router.

Workaround 2: Reorganize your LAN and router security settings.

- use the router's DHCP setup page to give static leases to all your LAN devices, and set up their IP addresses in a single subnet, let's say 192.168.0.0/27 or 192.168.0.2 thru 192.168.0.31 (assuming your router is 192.168.0.1)
- add security rules to the router to allow the 192.168.0.0/27 subnet access to the Internet
- add another security rule to block all other traffic
- change the DHCP pool to use another range, let's say 192.168.0.128-192.168.0.254

There are a couple of problems with Workaround #2: if you overlook the static lease for a device it won't be able to reach the Internet; when you plug in a new device you'll need to update the router settings to give it a static lease; and worst of all, a rogue user on your WiFi network could assign themselves an IP address on the "allowed" subnet and still get to the Internet.

Workaround #1, assuming you have the extra router on hand, is simpler to maintain and if you've set it up right there's no way a WiFi user can hack around it.

Comment: thank you, i think method 2 is a good one